# Updating location without triggering any controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `ngRoute` module for routing. Let's say I have this `person` object that I want to display to the user. I want this to be like facebook's photo, where you display a modal if you click it, and a non-modal if you type it directly to the bar.

How I do this is something like, I map `PersonController` to `/person/:id`, so if a user type it directly or open it from other site, it will display the `person` in a non-modal page (using `ngView`), and in the main page, I want to do something like:

```
<a href="" ngClick="displayModal(person)">{{ person.name }}</a>
```

It will open a modal, displaying the `person` AND the path will change to `/person/:id` so user can bookmark it. The problem is, this will trigger the `PersonController`, is there a way to update a location without triggering any/specific controller?

Thanks.